# Print negative number in RED in .xlsx file via E-mail

Tags: email, sas, xlsx

i have a data sales below, and I am trying to send it out via email with .xlsx file attached.
the question is that I want the cell(s) with negative number(i.e. -2.10%, -0.17%) in column 'change' to be red color:

```
    data sales;
     input unid $3. map change percent8.2;
     format change percent8.2;
      cards;
    001 100 12.00%
    002 509 -2.10%
    003 2001 -0.17%
    004 48   7.23%
    ;
    run;
```

Comment: Proc report with conditional formatting will do this. I'm assuming you're using ODS EXCEL to output your data? Example 13 in the documentation for PROC REPORT has examples on formatting fonts/background colors. https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=p0xcdcilo2yuuwn1t9uks2c1e66e.htm&locale=en

Answer (score 1):

When using `ODS EXCEL` the style attribute `tagattr` can be used to inject Excel specific features into worksheet cells.

In this case, Excel cell formatting can be applied, such that positive values are formatted one way and negative numbers another way.

[Review guidelines for customizing a number format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5), Microsoft Support

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> ```
> <POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
> ```
>
> For example, you can use these code sections to create the following custom format:
>
> ```
> [Blue]#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00);0.00;"sales "@
> ```

Example:

```
ods excel file='sample.xlsx';

proc print noobs data=sales;
  var unid map;
  var change / style=[tagattr='format:#0.00%;[Red](#0.00%)'];
run;

ods excel close;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure to upvote or mark the good answers and questions you come across.  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: one more question, if I want RED color for the cell if the column MAP=<100, i.e. 2 cells - MAP=100/48, what should I do?

Comment: For more complicated cell coloring, use Proc REPORT.  In the report code add something like `COMPUTE MAP; if map<=100 the call define ('MAP','STYLE','STYLE=[color=red]); ENDCOMP;`